# Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

"Я не знаю() что делать."

"Я не знаю() как быть."

"Я сам не знаю() почему, но..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Я не знаю, что делать."

"Я не знаю, как быть."

"Я сам не знаю почему, но..." - придаточное из одного союзного слова не отделяется как отдельное предложение, выполняет роль дополнения.